# Is there any other historical character in hell other than this character in Preacher?

Tags: character, preacher

In *Preacher S02E03*, due to the repeated breaking down of equipment, Eugene can leave his cell and encounters Hitler in the hallway. In the next episode he also meets many other hell-mates.

Are any of those other inmates also historical figures? If yes then whom?

Answer (score -2):

Apparently: The only identified person is Hitler. The rest are representative of a cross-section of society. So you have: Samurai guy (NOT Ghengis Khan), caveman, gypsy and so on.

In general, with questions like this, go to the network site first, or IMDB,